# Why does Angular 2 use string for template model?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, angular

I've been using React with TypeScript for a year. And the thing that makes me like React is that almost everything in React can be type safety when using TypeScript.

Angular 2, although, it was made for using with TypeScript but it still requires the use of "magic string" inside template. That makes me disappointed.

Example (with React):

```
class ClickMeComponent extends React.Component<{}, {clickMessage: string}> {
    state = {
        clickMessage = ""
    }

    onClickMe = () => {
        this.setState({clickMessage: "You are my hero!"});
    }

    render() {
        <button onClick={onClickMe}>Click me!</button>
        {this.state.clickMessage }
    }
}
```

Example (with Angular 2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'click-me',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
    {{clickMessage}}`
})
export class ClickMeComponent {
  clickMessage = '';

  onClickMe() {
    this.clickMessage = 'You are my hero!';
  }
}
```

The React's template is totally type safety but the Angular's one is using string "onClickMe()"

Why couldn't Angular team design it somehow to get type safety from TypeScript? Especially when they created Angular 2 to use with TypeScript at first?

Comment: will you please explain your question bit more ?

Comment: *"That makes me disappointed."*. Does native DOM event handlers like `onclick="onClickMe()"` also make you disappointing? Angular is closer to standard notation when it evaluate attribute, whilst React I guess uses function reference. Both are fine, but it's a matter of preference, I like eval way better, you are used to reference. But at the end it doesn't matter as long as you can set up event handlers somehow.

Comment: @dfsq It's not like that. In `onClick={onClickMe}`, onClickMe is a function, not a string with value of function name.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying: reference. So what?

Comment: Don't you think it'd be better with the use of reference instead of string (because of compile-time checking)? I just don't know why they didn't use reference.